# why is the sleep() command not work when I am writing in c++

Tags: c++

every time I use sleep() it just says its not recognized:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:16.5: error: 'sleep' was not declared in this scope
   16 |    sleep(2);
      |    ^~~~~
```

I keep looking it up but nothing seems to work

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    sleep(2);
    cout<<"hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sleep` is not a part of standard C++

Comment: The error is correct.  Neither your program nor `iostream` define a function named `sleep`.

Comment: Look here: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cpp-sleep/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));`

Comment: **sleep** is POSIX C function. `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: Note that if you're running on Windows, a non-POSIX operating system, there is `Sleep` rather than sleep, but `sleep` and `Sleep` are wildly different in the amount of time they sleep for the same input value. Use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) as suggested by Eljay as it works everywhere, assuming the compiler's less than a decade old.

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::chrono::system_clock;

auto now_str()
{
    auto now = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
    return std::ctime(&now);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start: " << now_str() << std::flush;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);

    std::cout << " Stop: " << now_str() << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ehqjYK1z5)

- [std::chrono_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h)
- [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)
- [system_clock::to_time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t)
- [std::ctime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime)